# finding closest x,y position in one list to an x,y position in another?

Tags: python, python-2.7, scipy

so I have two 2d lists with x and y coordinates and I want to go through list1, and for each point find the closest x,y coordinates in list2. They're of different lengths, and it's okay if I don't use all the points of list2 or even if I reuse points, as long as I go through all the points only once in list1. I need the shift itself as well as the location in the lists of both points. I tried using a function I found on this site but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
def do_kdtree(combined_x_y_arrays,points):
    mytree = scipy.spatial.cKDTree(combined_x_y_arrays)
    dist, indexes = mytree.query(points)
    return dist,indexes

#Perhaps it's not doing what I wanted it to do. Here is what I tried:

s_x = ([1.0,2.0,3.0])
s_y = ([1.5,2.5,3.5])
SDSS_x = ([3.0,4.0,5.0])
SDSS_y = ([3.5,4.5,5.5])

list1 = zip([s_x],[s_y])
list2 = zip([SDSS_x],[SDSS_y])


shift,place_in_array = do_kdtree(list1,list2)
```

and the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tester.py", line 23, in <module>
    shift,place_in_array = do_kdtree(list1,list2)
  File "tester.py", line 9, in do_kdtree
    mytree = scipy.spatial.cKDTree(combined_x_y_arrays)
  File "ckdtree.pyx", line 811, in scipy.spatial.ckdtree.cKDTree.__init__ (scipy/spatial/ckdtree.c:7157)
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

I get the impression this means the function wasn't expecting two-dimensional lists, which would mean this function isn't really doing what I wanted it to do. I'm not even sure what "indexes" is returning and if it really is the point in the list, which is what I was hoping it was. If that's the case, could someone tell me if there's an existing function I can use to do this?

Comment: Just a thought - the distance formula calculates the distance between two points. If you want a set with the closest distance. Compute the distance between the set. It is a naive solution, but it's a good start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are using `zip` wrongly, as it won't create an 2d-list for you:

```
 >>> s_x = ([1.0,2.0,3.0])
 >>> s_y = ([1.5,2.5,3.5])

 >>> list1_broken = zip([s_x],[s_y])
 >>> print list1_broken
 [([1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [1.5, 2.5, 3.5])]

 >>> list1 = zip(s_x,s_y)
 >>> print list1
 [(1.0, 1.5), (2.0, 2.5), (3.0, 3.5)]
```